# Inheritance of closure objects and overriding of methods

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, closures

I need to extend a class, which is encapsulated in a closure. This base class is following:

```
var PageController = (function(){

    // private static variable
    var _current_view;

return function(request, new_view) {
    ...

    // priveleged public function, which has access to the _current_view 
    this.execute = function() {
        alert("PageController::execute");
    }

}
})();
```

Inheritance is realised using the following function:

```
function extend(subClass, superClass){
var F = function(){
};
F.prototype = superClass.prototype;
subClass.prototype = new F();
subClass.prototype.constructor = subClass;
subClass.superclass = superClass.prototype;
StartController.cache = '';


if (superClass.prototype.constructor == Object.prototype.constructor) {
    superClass.prototype.constructor = superClass;
}
}
```

I subclass the PageController:

```
var StartController = function(request){
    // calling the constructor of the super class
    StartController.superclass.constructor.call(this, request, 'start-view');
}
// extending the objects
extend(StartController, PageController);

// overriding the PageController::execute
StartController.prototype.execute = function() {
alert('StartController::execute');
}
```

Inheritance is working. I can call every PageController's method from StartController's instance. However, method overriding doesn't work:

```
var startCont = new StartController();
startCont.execute();
```

alerts "PageController::execute".
How should I override this method?

Comment: Why are you using a closure for PageController? It looks like _current_view could be declared in the constructor just as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because `StartController` calls `PageController` which adds an `execute` property to your object, so the `execute` property of `StartController.prototype` is not used.

For your overriding to work, you have to either :

1) define `PageController.prototype.execute` as the `execute` method of `PageController`. It won't work because then the function doesn't have access to `_current_view`.

2) define `StartController.execute` in the object constructor :

```
var StartController = function(request){
    // calling the constructor of the super class
    StartController.superclass.constructor.call(this, request, 'start-view');
    // overriding the PageController::execute
    this.execute = function() {
      alert('StartController::execute');
    }
}
// extending the objects
extend(StartController, PageController);
```

edit:

So you want for `StartController.execute` to access `_current_view`, which is impossible as long as `_current_view` is part of a closure that `StartController` is not part of. You might have to proceed like this:

```
(function () {
  var _current_view;
  window.PageController = function(request, new_view) {
   ...
   this.execute = function() { ... }
  }

  window.StartController = function(request) {
    StartController.superclass.constructor.call(this, request, 'start-view');
    this.execute = function() { ... }
  }
  extend(StartController, PageController);

}()
var startCont = new StartController();
startCont.execute();
```

And if you want some kind of protected behavior, you might want to try this trick:

```
(function() {
  var token = {};

 window.Class1 = function() {
    this.protectedMethod = function(tok) {
      if(tok != token) return; // unauthorized
      ...
    }
  }

  window.Class2 = function() {
    new Class1().protectedMethod(token); // access granted
  }
})()

new Class1().protectedMethod(); // access denied
```

There's no such thing as a package in javascript, so your possibilities are limited. You can certainly not have any kind of privileges among functions/objects/constructors that are not part of the same script. None that I know of, at least. Except maybe querying a server for some kind of authorization.

Comment: The second method doesn't have the access to _current_view either. However, now I'm not sure that my design decision with closure was right. _current_view is static and private, but I need an access to _current_view from subclasses and this is more like a "protected" behaviour. I could make public accessor methods for _current_view, but it would allow everybody to modify _current_view and I want to avoid this.
Btw, are there any techniques to emulate "protected" variables?

Comment: Yes, there are. I will update my answer to help you on that point. But my current answer fits your question, since you didn't ask for StartController to access _current_view, right?

Comment: Thank you for your truly detailed and comprehensive answer. I think, I'm starting to understand concepts of JavaScript better. Thanks!